# Symbolic operation on Ti-84 calculator

Tags: calculator

I want the calculator to answer with the parameter answer, not with a numeric value, I have tried to clear "M" variable with no success. 
Any idea?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y36vz.jpg

( sorry I don't have enough reputation to post image directly here)

Comment: I don't know if a TI-83 or 84 can do that. The TI-89 can for sure.

Comment: It's only a $3\times 3$ matrix...why not just do it by hand?

Comment: This is just a quick example to demonstrate my problem, I wanted to know if I could do these "symbolic operation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do "symbolic manipulations" with the TI-84. You would need a TI-89 or something equivalent. The TI-84 will only be able to give you numerical answers. When you clear a variable, you are setting the variable equal to zero. So, you are really just computing the determinant:
$$
det \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1  & 0}
$$
which is equal to $2$.